Primary impedance of the ideal transformer
When a load with an R value is connected to the secondary of an ideal transformer, logically, the secondary impedance becomes equal to R. We can indeed see this in the circuit schematic. However, I don't understand the primary impedance. We connect the voltage source directly to the primary of the transformer, with nothing in between. In this case, why is there a primary impedance? And if there is, why don't we represent it with a resistor symbol? Lastly, the primary inductance is represented by an arrow. What does this signify?
One thing that confuses me is whether these two circuits are equivalent. Are they the same circuits?

The picture is taken from this link: http://www.vias.org/matsch_capmag/matsch_caps_magnetics_chap6_04_04.html

Have you applied the definition of a transformer? An impdance?

That's I for Current, not I for Impedance


In this case, why is there a primary impedance? And if there is, why don't we represent it with a resistor symbol?

If you want to constrain the load to being just a resistor, then you can certainly do so.  This diagram is simply saying that the theory can be extended to be more general, ie: it applies to any load that is made up of any combination of R, L, & C.
So in simple terms: yes, if the load that was connected to the secondary was just a resistor, then the equivalent circuit showing the load referred to the primary would be just a resistor also.

One thing that confuses me is whether these two circuits are equivalent. Are they the same circuits?

They are not physically identical, but they are electrically equivalent if you only consider the values of V1 and I1.
Imagine you are an electrical power supply: you have two terminals, you put out a constant voltage V1 across these terminals, and you can measure the current that flows out of your terminals (I1), but you are blind; that is, you cannot see what is physically connected to your terminals - you can only "see" electrical quantities voltage and current.  If circuit (a) was connected (the circuit with the transformer), which caused a current of I1 to flow, and then circuit (b) was connected (the circuit without the transformer), you would not be able to tell the difference, because I1 was the same in both cases.  That is the meaning of electrical equivalence.

Lastly, the primary inductance is represented by an arrow. What does this signify?

No, that is not inductance, it signifies the current flow out of voltage source "V1".

This is simply showing that the secondary load is reflected to the primary.
Imagine it’s 1:2 with 10V on the primary and 20 ohms on the secondary.
10V becomes 20V becomes 1A or 20 watts.
Reflect 20W back to the 10V primary and it’s 2A or 5 ohms.  This matches the equation given.
The triangles represent current not inductance.
